# Can't touch UIButton inside custom programmatic UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have `MasterChatViewController` in which I added as a subview a custom UIView called `JFShapedNavBar`.  Inside the `JFShapedNavBar` I added a subview of `UIButton` with an image and added a target-action to a method that just prints something to the console in order to debug right now.

`MasterChatViewController` contains `JFShapedNavBar` **and**
`JFShapedNavBar` contains `UIButton`.

I use `Masonry` to setup constraints. When I initialize the views I use a custom variant of `initWithFrame:CGRectZero`:

```
_shapedNavBar = [[JFShapedNavBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero
forViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:_shapedNavBar];
[_shapedNavBar mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.leading.trailing.equalTo(self.view);
}];
```

Inside the `JFShapedNavBar.m`:

```
-(void)configureRightButton {
    // Right Button of Nav
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LobbyButton"];
    _rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_rightButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(testTouch) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:_rightButton];
    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}

-(void)testTouch {
    NSLog(@"You managed to figure out what you were doing wrong.");
}

-(void)updateConstraints {
    [super updateConstraints];

    [_arcShadow mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.leading.trailing.equalTo(self);
        make.height.equalTo(__navHeight);
    }];

    [_arcDrop mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.edges.equalTo(_arcShadow);
        make.height.equalTo(_arcShadow.mas_height);
    }];

    [_rightButton mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(self).offset(24);
        make.trailing.equalTo(self).offset(-16);
        make.height.equalTo(@30);
    }];

}
```

Ultimately, I am attempting to create a custom navigation bar (but not a subclass of the one in UIKit). I experimented for approximately 2 hours trying to figure out why the target-action handler doesn't fire, but now I am frustrated and out of ideas. Why can I not **touch** the UIButton?

Maybe this matters, I don't know, but on my view controller `MasterChatViewController` I have set hidden the navigation bar `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;`

Comment: Apparently, even though it was displaying properly at the correct height, the actual frame height was inadvertently kept at size zero. I know, I set the frame to `CGRectZero`, but for some reason I expected it to resize itself based on its content. It **was** displaying correctly, after all. I found the problem by observing the frame of the `shapedNavBar` and noticed it was `(0, 0, 375, 0)`.

Answer (score 3):

This won't solve your problem, but just some standard things to do for debugging tappable issues

1) temporarily set the background of all the buttons to green (so that you can see where their hit areas extend to

2) set userInteraction = YES on the children, and superview containers (sometimes)

3) look out for any gesture recognizer that may be swallowing your touches

4) make sure the button that is inside of the container view is inside of its bounds.. if its not, it wont be tappable

5) To further investigate layout issues, use Reveal or xcodes built in rip off of it for view debugging http://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6

Comment: These are all great tips, thank you for that. I attempted all of them. I found the solution to my problem - I wrote a comment on my answer if you're interested in reading it.

Comment: anytime, glad to you got it fixed :)